# What is the age of Naru in “Prey” (2022)

Tags: plot-explanation, character, prey

The main protagonist in “Prey” (2022) is a young Comanche woman who, while trained as a healer, would like to be a hunter.

So she goes off to hunt some deer and before you know it… Boy howdy does she get into one doozy of a predicament when a Predator shows up!

Anyway, how old is she? The implication in the film is she’s possibly in her late teens? But is there any definitive reference in the film (or supporting material) to indicate exactly what her age is?

PS: Some believe that the age of the character is the same as the age of the actress who portrayed her, Amber Midthunder, who is 25 years old.

But I contend that Naru being 25 years old doesn’t add up in the context of the journey of someone who was trained as a healer yet is going on their first hunt. 25 seems too old for a first hunt. To me, someone in a case like this would be 19 to 21 years old.

[image: Naru herself.]

---

***I am looking for an answer that cites the filmmakers themselves in some clear capacity. While information on Native American rites of passive *might* help, that historical context is just that: Historical. Actual references regarding Naru’s age from the filmmakers themselves is what I am looking for.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Naru is 19

According to an early casting call found on [Tribal Film Festival](https://www.facebook.com/Tribalfilmf/posts/2219226778383593) Facebook page, Naru is 19.

The character’s original name was “Kee.”

> “KEE Female; 19 years old; Comanche. Her name, “Kee”, means “no” in Comanche. A name she has earned by perpetually refusing to do as she is told her entire life. Kee is very close to her younger brother, Taabe, who is being groomed as a leader. As capable as any young man in the tribe, Kee has always been a teacher and source of inspiration for Taabe. In the Comanche way – she is “Patsi” – the elder sister that has helped to shape him. Kee is a truth teller and has insight that others do not. A tomboy, she wants to prove herself in the masculine world of the Comanche. When danger threatens them all – Kee sets out to prove that she is as capable as any young warrior.”

Comment: This "original character" is clearly different from the actual movie protagonist.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know exactly how old is *Naru* in *Prey* (2022), but here some information from Wikipedia that might lead us to think that she would be somewhere between the ages of 12 and 17. Bold emphasis is mine.

> “Boys were highly respected because they would become warriors and might die young in battle. As he approached manhood, a boy went on his first buffalo hunt. If he made a kill, his father honored him with a feast. Only after he had proven himself on a buffalo hunt was a young man allowed to go to war.
>
> **When he was ready to become a warrior, at about age 15 or 16, a young man first "made his medicine" by going on a vision quest (a rite of passage). Following this quest, his father gave him a good horse to ride into battle and another mount for the trail.** If he had proved himself as a warrior, a Give Away Dance might be held in his honor. As drummers faced east, the honored boy and other young men danced. His parents, along with his other relatives and the people in the band, threw presents at his feet – especially blankets and horses symbolized by sticks. Anyone might snatch one of the gifts for themselves, although those with many possessions refrained; they did not want to appear greedy. People often gave away all their belongings during these dances, providing for others in the band, but leaving themselves with nothing.
>
> Girls learned to gather berries, nuts, and roots. They carried water and collected wood, and at about 12 years old learned to cook meals, make tipis, sew clothing, prepare hides, and perform other tasks essential to becoming a wife and mother. They were then considered ready to be married.”

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comanche